# jQuery: Compare arrays with same keys and fill gaps

Tags: jquery

```
arrayA = [
  ['10-01', "foo"],
  ['10-02', "bar"],
  ['10-03', "baz"]
];

arrayB = [
  ['10-01', 1],
  ['10-03', 3]
];
```

arrayA is a continous date list with unimportant values.

In arrayB I want to fill the missing dates ('10-02') to read "0". Therefor I want to use the keys of arrayA as map (both start at the same date though).

Then the array would read

```
arrayB = [
  ['10-01', 1],
  ['10-02', 0],
  ['10-03', 3]
];
```

I have no idea how to :/

Test: https://jsfiddle.net/x37zor7y/1/

Comment: what are the values of arrayB representing?

Comment: Values of arrayB are count values from MySQL

Comment: Where do 1 and 3 come from for 10-01 and 10-03? Not sure what you're actually trying to do here

Comment: It's a lucky workaround in JS for MySQL gaps from grouping timestamps. Say arrayA is a visitor list (values are the ammount of unique vistors) and arrayB is the number of sales (which can have days with no sales = no timestamp in the mysql table). In my chart I want the these gaps to read 0 instead of being ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map both arrays into a new set of arrays with just the date values.

Then loop over the continuous one and fill in holes if the value doesn't already exist in non continuous array

```
var allDates = arrayA.map(function(subArr){
    return subArr[0];
});

var arrBDates = arrayB.map(function(subArr){
    return subArr[0];
});

allDates.forEach(function(dateVal){
    if(arrBDates.indexOf(dateVal) ==-1){
       arrayB.push([dateVal, 0]) 
    }
});
// sort updated arrayB
 arrayB.sort(function(a,b){
   return a[0]>b[0]
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/x37zor7y/5/)**</kbd>

Comment: Your previous edit works: https://jsfiddle.net/x37zor7y/6/ `arrayB.sort();` does the trick for me

Answer (score 1):

Your fastest approach would be to convert the arrays to objects (as the `10-x` are unique keys), merge them, and convert them back. This way the JavaScript engine can use something like a HashMap to check for existence and the complexity goes from `O(n^2)` to `O(n)` roughly.

```js
var arrayA = [
      ['10-1', 'foo'],
      ['10-2', 'bar'],
      ['10-3', 'baz']
    ],
    arrayB = [
      ['10-1', 1],
      ['10-3', 3]
    ];

function twodimensionalArrayToObject(array) {
  return array.reduce(function(obj, entry) {
    obj[entry[0]] = entry[1];
    return obj;
  }, {});
}

function objectToTwodimensionalArray(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
    return[key, obj[key]];
  });
}

function extendWithZeros(obj1, obj2) {
  for (var key in obj2) {
    if (obj2.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      if (!obj1.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        obj1[key] = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  return obj1;
}

document.write(
  JSON.stringify(
    objectToTwodimensionalArray(
      extendWithZeros(
        twodimensionalArrayToObject(arrayB),
        twodimensionalArrayToObject(arrayA)
      )
    )
  )
);
```